# How can I use Parse push-notifications without using Parse as my database?

Tags: php, mysql, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to send pushes, but i am using MySQL as my database. Can I use Parse push-notification without using Parse as my database or which push-service should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an account and handle the push registration requirements then yes. The parse database would contain only installations and you would need to apply some scheme with channels if you wanted to filter who notifications are sent to.